# SearchView results list width

Tags: android

Is there a way to make SearchView's results list occupy whole screen width? I've tried using custom layout for SearchView, but this doesn't change the search results list's width. 
See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think search result width depends on search edit text width

Comment: @Praveen in my CursorAdapter I inflate view with width MATCH_PARENt.

Comment: post your code and custom adapter layout

Comment: Do you use `AppCompat`?

Comment: Have you tried [setDropDownWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownWidth(int))? If not try calling `setDropDownWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)` on `AutoCompleteTextView` instance. Even you can try `setDropDownWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To achieve this we should set width of whole `DropDownView`, not only for items. We can set it by calling `setDropDownWidth` of `AutoCompleteTextView`. But there is one problem. `DropDownView`'s width and horizontal offset are calculated inside `SearchView` each time its bounds is changed. To get a workaround we can add to `SearchView` our own `OnLayoutChangeListener` where we calculate and set the height of `DropDownView`. The following code is fully working with `AppCompat`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // inflate our menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    // find MenuItem and get SearchView from it
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    // id of AutoCompleteTextView
    int searchEditTextId = R.id.search_src_text; // for AppCompat

    // get AutoCompleteTextView from SearchView
    final AutoCompleteTextView searchEditText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchEditTextId);
    final View dropDownAnchor = searchView.findViewById(searchEditText.getDropDownAnchor());
    if (dropDownAnchor != null) {
        dropDownAnchor.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                       int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

                // calculate width of DropdownView


                int point[] = new int[2];
                dropDownAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(point);
                // x coordinate of DropDownView
                int dropDownPadding = point[0] + searchEditText.getDropDownHorizontalOffset();

                Rect screenSize = new Rect();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRectSize(screenSize);
                // screen width
                int screenWidth = screenSize.width();

                // set DropDownView width
                searchEditText.setDropDownWidth(screenWidth - dropDownPadding * 2);
            }
        });
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**If you use Holo** just change the line `int searchEditTextId = R.id.search_src_text;` to the below one:

```
int searchEditTextId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
```

Comment: God, I hate the SearchView widget

Comment: This work only for Android 5.0+. But I need for Android 4.3

Answer (score -1):

You must get reference to SearchAutoComplete object which in my case android.support.v7.widget.SearchView using , then set its size , please check my answer here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43480908/5255624