# Android searchView drop down menu screen width

Tags: android, searchview, search-suggestion

**Situation:**

I have a searchview widget in my appcompat toolbar that allows custom suggestions via sqlitedatabase.

**Problem:**

I am having trouble expanding the drop down suggestions list to be the full width of the screen. At best, the list width is almost the width of the screen except for small margin/padding problems on the left and right side. How do I make the drop down list have the same width as the screen?

**Things I've tried:**

[SearchView results list width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299260/searchview-results-list-width)

AutoCompleteText's setPadding, setRight/setLeft, setDropDownHorizontalOffset, setting layout params, and setting width to be match_parent.

menu/search.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_restaurant"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

res/search_view_suggestions_list_item

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

activity/Activity.java

```
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_restaurant);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Restaurant");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    final AutoCompleteTextView searchAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView
            .findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // Tried to change margins/padding here
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
            searchAutoCompleteTextView.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHorizontalOffset(-100);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setLeft(0);

    final View dropDownSuggestions = searchView.findViewById(searchAutoCompleteTextView
            .getDropDownAnchor());
    if (dropDownSuggestions != null) {
        dropDownSuggestions.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                int point[] = new int[2];

                dropDownSuggestions.getLocationOnScreen(point);
                int dropDownPadding = point[0] + searchAutoCompleteTextView
                        .getDropDownHorizontalOffset();

                Rect screenSize = new Rect();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRectSize(screenSize);
                int screenWidth = screenSize.width();
                searchAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(screenWidth * 2);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of the width you want, can be achieve by using Wrap content .
Try this code:
searchAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

I came to this answer when i went through this link:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=408pMAQFnvs

Comment: I tried adding it outside of addOnLayoutChangeListener and then inside. There was no difference from my original code.

Comment: ok please use AutocompleteTextview in xml instead of textview and keep layout_width ="fill parent ".

Answer (score 0):

You must get reference to SearchAutoComplete object which SearchView using , then set its size and change the background resource which has padding's, please refer to my answer here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481639/5255624